# Authentication Scenarios except Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get azure metric data but prior to do that i have to do authentication. I have done the authentication part with Azure AD now i want to know is there any other way to authenticate without using Azure AD.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK , No .Azure Metrics can be accessed via the Azure Monitor APIs , with that rest apis you need to use Azure Resource Manager authentication model , that means all requests must be authenticated with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)